# Unstacking DataFrame with Multiple 'Value' Columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stack, pivot-table

Say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     keys    sample   verify  
0    foo       a        1      
1    bar       b        2      
2   monty      c        3      
3    foo       d        4      
4    bar       e        5   
5   monty      f        6
```

That I want in this form:

```
     foo_1    bar_1    monty_1  foo_2  bar_2  monty_2
0     a        b        c        1      2       3
1     d        e        f        4      5       6
```

What is the best way of unstacking? I have tried both pandas.pivot_table() and the pandas.unstack() function but the pivot table wont work with alphabetic values and the unstack function doesn't work the way I think it should (i.e. inverse of stack). I assume you could unstack column by column and join the dataframes at the end, the problem I am mostly having is with the unstack function and what it is doing. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = df.set_index('keys').T.reset_index(drop=True) \
    .T.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)) \
    .stack().unstack(1).T

df2.columns = df2.columns.set_levels((df2.columns.levels[1] + 1).astype(str), level=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().str.join('_')

df2
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thanks a ton

Comment: @sfortney glad I could help